# Grouping Based on Similarity in Percentage

Tags: oracle, grouping

I have a table that looks like this:

```
username | privilges 
user1       privilge1
user1       privilge2
user1       privilge3
user2       privilge1
user2       privilge5
user2       privilge3
etc ......
```

I would like to group privliges based on similarity in percentage to other user.
for example in the table  :
user1 and user2 has only 2 privilges in common (privilge1,privilge3) which are 66%. 
so if I search for similarities in priviges based on more then 50% it will group it like this:

```
user1  : privilge1 ,privilge3
user2  : privilge1 ,privilge3
```

Comment: How many users ? If it is more than two, do you want to compare every user with every other user. If so, how should the results be displayed ?

Comment: there are 5000 users with more the 17000 privilges . i want to run a query against the table with different value for the comparasion percentage  in order to define group of users based on their similarities and then create roles by it . this is why it had to be run for all users (compare privleges set of each user to other ) the percentage will allow me to define different groups (100% similarity is only one group) . the results should be show as list of users and their common privilges . Thanks , Zohar

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Stack Overflow: How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and [John Skeet's Question Checklist](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist.aspx) to find out how to ask a good question that will generate good useful, answers.