# How to group text data based on document similarity?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, nltk, similarity

Consider the dataframe like below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Questions': ['What are you doing?','What are you doing tonight?','What are you doing now?','What is your name?','What is your nick name?','What is your full name?','Shall we meet?',
                             'How are you doing?' ]})
```

```
                   Questions
0          What are you doing?
1  What are you doing tonight?
2      What are you doing now?
3           What is your name?
4      What is your nick name?
5      What is your full name?
6               Shall we meet?
7           How are you doing?
```

How to group the dataframe with similar Questions? i.e how to get groups like below

```
for _, i in df.groupby('similarity')['Questions']:
    print(i,'\n')
```

```
6    Shall we meet?
Name: Questions, dtype: object 

3         What is your name?
4    What is your nick name?
5    What is your full name?
Name: Questions, dtype: object 

0            What are you doing?
1    What are you doing tonight?
2        What are you doing now?
7             How are you doing?
Name: Questions, dtype: object
```

A similar question was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1329376/grouping-based-on-similarity-in-percentage) but with less clarity so no aswers for that question

Comment: Actually, for problems like this, NLP/cosine similarities really are the best ways to move forward.

Comment: Yeah I'm working on it now. Will surely update as soon as I succeed. Still a beginner. :). A solution from you would be great too : )

Comment: NLP or maybe fuzzywuzzy

Comment: @Wen fuzzywuzzy sounds promising but havent used it yet. Can you add a solution based on that.?

Comment: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/52213/ maybe you can do more research base on you own data, cause NPL design is variety , it all depends on the data you are working with.

Comment: @Wen that code gives soundex and mine was to generalize and group the similar documents by computing similarity score.  What do you think about my answer?

Comment: Firstly, how do you define similarity?

Comment: Sentences that almost mean the same?

Comment: Not a good definition. It would be too vague for any serious application =(

Comment: Still a beginner I jus came across document similarity using sysnets and was curious to group data based on that score. So thought of sharing my answer. I agree it's too broad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's one pretty big approach by finding the `normalized similarity score` between all the elements in the series and then grouping them by the newly obtained similarity list converted to string. i.e

```
import numpy as np
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
import pandas as pd

def convert_tag(tag):   
    tag_dict = {'N': 'n', 'J': 'a', 'R': 'r', 'V': 'v'}
    try:
        return tag_dict[tag[0]]
    except KeyError:
        return None

def doc_to_synsets(doc):
    """
    Returns a list of synsets in document.

    Tokenizes and tags the words in the document doc.
    Then finds the first synset for each word/tag combination.
    If a synset is not found for that combination it is skipped.

    Args:
        doc: string to be converted

    Returns:
        list of synsets

    Example:
        doc_to_synsets('Fish are nvqjp friends.')
        Out: [Synset('fish.n.01'), Synset('be.v.01'), 
     Synset('friend.n.01')]
    """

    synsetlist =[]
    tokens=nltk.word_tokenize(doc)
    pos=nltk.pos_tag(tokens)    
    for tup in pos:
        try:
            synsetlist.append(wn.synsets(tup[0], convert_tag(tup[1]))[0])
        except:
            continue           
    return synsetlist

def similarity_score(s1, s2):
    """
    Calculate the normalized similarity score of s1 onto s2

    For each synset in s1, finds the synset in s2 with the largest similarity value.
    Sum of all of the largest similarity values and normalize this value by dividing it by the number of largest similarity values found.

    Args:
        s1, s2: list of synsets from doc_to_synsets

    Returns:
        normalized similarity score of s1 onto s2

    Example:
        synsets1 = doc_to_synsets('I like cats')
        synsets2 = doc_to_synsets('I like dogs')
        similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2)
        Out: 0.73333333333333339
    """

    highscores = []
    for synset1 in s1:
        highest_yet=0
        for synset2 in s2:
            try:
                simscore=synset1.path_similarity(synset2)
                if simscore>highest_yet:
                    highest_yet=simscore
            except:
                continue

        if highest_yet>0:
             highscores.append(highest_yet)  

    return sum(highscores)/len(highscores)  if len(highscores) > 0 else 0

def document_path_similarity(doc1, doc2):
    synsets1 = doc_to_synsets(doc1)
    synsets2 = doc_to_synsets(doc2)
    return (similarity_score(synsets1, synsets2) + similarity_score(synsets2, synsets1)) / 2


def similarity(x,df):
    sim_score = []
    for i in df['Questions']:
        sim_score.append(document_path_similarity(x,i))
    return sim_score
```

From the above methods defined we can now do

```
df['similarity'] = df['Questions'].apply(lambda x : similarity(x,df)).astype(str)

for _, i in df.groupby('similarity')['Questions']:
    print(i,'\n')
```

Output :

```
6    Shall we meet?
Name: Questions, dtype: object 

3         What is your name?
4    What is your nick name?
5    What is your full name?
Name: Questions, dtype: object 

0            What are you doing?
1    What are you doing tonight?
2        What are you doing now?
7             How are you doing?
Name: Questions, dtype: object
```

This isn't the best approach to the problem, and is really slow. Any new approach is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is a wonderful solution. I tried it for a small dataset and it works great. However, for a bigger dataset (1000 rows), it is super slow... I am also actively working on it. I will share the link if it works. Thank you again.

Comment: @Sophia its been a long time since I answered this question, feel free to suggest any edits / improvements if you come across any.

Comment: Your solution is a milestone for sure. I am coping with a much larger dataset and want to perform similar analysis, and it is very challenging. Any suggestion or input since I am new to NLP...? Thank you.

Comment: @Sophia one suggestion to speed things up you can start running the above by dividing your dataset to smaller batches and try running them across multiple threads.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. If we divide the dataset to smaller batches and make pairwise comparisons, then it will probably introduce bias into our grouping... Just 2c.

Answer (score 0):

You should sort all the names in the list/dataframe column first and then run the similarity code for only for n-1 rows i.e. for every row, compare it with the next element.
if the two are similar, you can categorize them as 1 or else 0 and parse through the list.
instead of comparing each row with every other element which is n^2.

Comment: This approach will save the computation time, but the similarity vector'e length will vary, and how can we use it to group the data?